# Chart.js - How to create an auto-scaling line diagram for a big amount of data happenning over time

Tags: javascript, date, chart.js, data-visualization, chartjs-2.6.0

So I have a relatively big amount of data that I want to display on the line chart by using `chart.js`.

**The problem**

My dataset looks like so:

```
 [{label: 'Mon Feb 19 2018 21:02:38 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: 0.2 },
  {label: 'Mon Feb 19 2018 21:02:39 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: 0.1 },
  {label: 'Mon Feb 19 2018 21:02:40 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: 0.5 },
  {label: 'Mon Feb 19 2018 21:02:41 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: -0.3 },
  {label: 'Mon Feb 19 2018 21:02:52 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: -0.3 }]
```

I am able to create a chart from this data that contains 5 labels on XAxis and 5 records on YAxis. Easy peasy.

So my records happen in a few seconds one after another and this is very easy to put on the chart. However, I cumulate the data over time so my first time can be:

```
{label: 'Mon Feb 19 2018 21:02:38 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: 0.2 }, ...
{label: 'Mon Feb 26 2018 11:02:38 GMT+0000 (GMT)', value: 0.2 }]
```

Therefore, the data now on the graph should be `auto-scaled` showing properly the line over that from the first date to the last date from the period with some labels in between.

The only ways that I came up with were focusing on serialising my data, but this is a very hard and tedious way.
I do not want to be re-inventing the wheel if that could be handled within the library.
From what I have seen so far this is a very powerful library and I think that such thing can be handled if the library is used properly.

I would really appreciate if anyone who has the experience with this library could help me out with writing a code for this task, or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-charts) may be what you need. You basically just need to push the new points onto the existing label and value arrays and call the chart's update method.